# when calling a method in a object it's says it's not a function

Tags: javascript

foo.bar() bar() is not a function

I am trying to call a method on and object but it says the x is not a function

```
var UIController = (function () {

    return {

        getInput: function () {

            return {

                type: document.querySelector('.add__type').value,
                description: document.querySelector('.add__description').value,
                value: document.querySelector('.add__value').value
            }
        }
    }

})
console.log(UIController.getInput());
```

when I log it it says getInput() is not a functoin

Comment: You defined `UIController` as a function, it doesn't have a `getInput` property; if you want the object the function returns, you have to call the function

Comment: UIController is an IIFE function.  when it runs it immediately create an object.

Comment: It's not an IIFE, it's just a function in parentheses. You're missing both the *Immediate* and *Invocation* part for it to be an actual IIFE.

Comment: yeah I missed the invocation. and it's why my code is not working

Answer (score 0):

var UIController is a function, not a object.

Look again, difference of function and object.

Object:

```
var UIController = {
 key : value

}
```

Function :

```
var UIController = function (){
....
}
```

So youcan call with UIController().getInput()

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your definition to get an instance of that inner object you return, which actually contains the `getInput` method, like so:

```js
var UIController = (function () {

    return {
        getInput: function () {
          console.log('foo')
        }
    }
})

var instance = UIController();
instance.getInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer the problem is with my IIFE function I shoud just add "()" this braces at the end of my function an it will work

```
var UIController = (function () {

return {
    getInput: function () {
      console.log('foo')
    }
}
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

UIController is function as you asigned it so 
Call like this console.log(UIController().getInput())
Because UIController is also returning a function.